# Is there any libary like Weka.jar (java) for matlab for text document indexing?

Tags: java, matlab, weka

I am working with Weka and needed to add another classifier Rocchio which is not supported currently in Weka. I was wondering is there any way to code for Rocchio in java and use the document pre-processing functionality from weka ?

I already coded Rocchio in matlab so is there any library like weka.jar (java) for matlab which can ease my work of document pre-processing and vector creation from text documents ?

Initially i thought to use text document to word vector conversion by using RapidMiner or Weka and then code and operate on those vector to classify them but traning data vector and test data vector generated from these tools have different vocabulary-dimensions. In short i want to avoid this whole process of document preprocessing & conversion into vectors and want to utilize my time in classifying document.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a Java-Library? You can run java-code directly via the matlab command line. Check the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/using-java-libraries-in-matlab.html).